# how to stretch the first left, right, top, and bottom row/column of image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a satellite image and I want to show an example of multi-scale.
so what I did is, add zeros (black pixels) around the image and put the image in the centre. now how can I fill the zeros from the first left, right, top, and bottom pixel row/column?
[image]

Matlab code:

```
img=imread ('example.jpg');
padcam = padarray(img,[1000 1000],'both');
```

EDIT:
[image]
Maybe it is easy explain from this image. Is this image what I want is to repeat the sea part in such a ways at the black area that it looks like we have large empty sea and small ships at the centre. That's why I have made red lines that I want to repeat/make copy/extend first left, right, top, and bottom pixel row/column so that make image at centre and black will be converted to pixels values of first left, right, top, and bottom pixel row/column.

Comment: Not clear what do you mean by "fill the zeros"

Comment: at the moment I have zeros around the image. Instead of zeros I want to put the pixel values of  first left, right, top, and bottom row/column to that.

Comment: Use imrezise instruction and put the results in your padarray function.

Comment: I think @Shai , have provided the answer you're seeking, if you think it is not, let me know to post my answer.

Comment: @MimSaad you can post your answer too. let me check that too maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: @MimSaad Can you please upload your solution?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is what you have meant...

Instead of fill zeros, start from the highest resolution, and place lower resolution images at the center of each other.

Here is my code sample (you may use a `for` loop instead):

```
I0 = imread('peppers.png');
I0 = padarray(I0,[16 16],'both'); %I0 - full resolution.
I1 = imresize(I0, 0.5);           %I1 - half resolution.
I2 = imresize(I0, 0.25);          %I2 - quarter resolution.

J = I0;

%Place I1 at the center of J.
J(1+(end-size(I1,1))/2:(end+size(I1,1))/2, 1+(end-size(I1,2))/2:(end+size(I1,2))/2, :) = I1;

%Place I2 at the center of J.
J(1+(end-size(I2,1))/2:(end+size(I2,1))/2, 1+(end-size(I2,2))/2:(end+size(I2,2))/2, :) = I2;

figure;imshow(J);
```

Result:
[image]

---

Check the following:
The example is basted on Matlab documentation of [imtransform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtransform.html)

```
I = imresize(imread('peppers.png'), 0.5);
A = [1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1];
T = maketform('affine', A);
R = makeresampler({'cubic', 'nearest'}, 'replicate');
J = imtransform(I, T, R, 'XData', [-size(I,2), size(I,2)*2], 'YData', [-size(I,1), size(I,1)*2]);
figure;imshow(J);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Rotem, but I want is to just show the lower scale image at centre and the remaining part should be purple background like as the top row, bottom row, first column and last column is purple so it is extended/repeated to the size of original image. So we will have large purple background and in centre small vegetables. have you got what I mean to say?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [`'replicate'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) padding option:

```
padcam = padarray(img,[1000 1000],'both', 'replicate');
```

resulting with:
[image]

If you are looking for smoother result, consider using [`regionfill`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionfill.html).

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me how can I use `regionfill`?